# ListBox shows (Collection) instead of object's ToString() when List of Collections is bound

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a ListBox which is bound to an instance of a list of elements of Class A, which is a collection.

```
class A : List<B> 
{ 
  public override ToString()
  {
    return "A";
  }
}

class C
{
  List<A> list;
}
```

ListBox:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding list}"></ListBox>
```

When the application is run, every item shows "(Collection)"

What can I do to make each item show "A" instead of "Collection"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I did the following:

```
class A : IEnumerable
{
  private List<B> _bList = new List<B>();

  public override ToString()
  {
    return "A";
  }

  IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
  {
    return _bList.GetEnumerator();
  }

  public void Add(B element){
  {
    _bList.Add(element);
  }
}

class C
{
  List<A> list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ItemsSource is expecting the property to be IEnumerable, so it's binding to the contents of the collection instead of the List object directly.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do to make each item show
>   "A" instead of "Collection"?

You need to override the `ToString` method on the list items (B) **not** the list itself (A).

```
public class B 
{
   public override ToString()
   {
      return "A";
   }
}
```

Comment: Every item in the ListBox is binded to an instance of A class.
A is a Collection of B objects.
My goal is to bind a List of A objects to ListBox, so that every item shows for example:
"item contains 30 B objects"
"item contains 14 B objects"

instead of this each item shows "(Collection)"